# Preventing XSS using Amazon JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, xss

I'm using the Amazon JavaScript SDK to save and load data to DynamoDB.

Users are restricted to only write/update to rows that match their FB id, using IAM profiles:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXX:table/Items"],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${graph.facebook.com:id}"]
        }
      }
  }]
}
```

And an IAM profile to allow them read each others data:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:Scan"
      ],
      "Resource": ["*"]
  }]
}
```

However this means all users can read each others data, which leads to a possible XSS attack e.g.:

- User 1 writes a new record with alert('xss') instead of the image url
- User 2, 3 etc load the site and view User 1's image url and it triggers the popup.

I created a test write and read and it seems the Amazon SDK does not do any sanitisation to prevent XSS attacks. This is what I get back:

```
{
    "Type": { "S": "instrumental" },
    "FileType": { "S": "audio/mp3" },
    "ItemId": { "S": "Albany" },
    "Name": { "S": "Manuel - Albany" },
    "Time": { "S": "1427245718743" },
    "UserId": { "S": "10152604048816638javascript:alert('XSS');" },
    "GroupId": { "S": "43mi7o18xkf"}
}
```

I have looked at some solutions for example the mustache libray escaping here:

```
var entityMap = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
        return entityMap[s];
    });
}
```

But this solution doesn't work for json data and i'm not sure this accounts for all attack methods listed here:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Ideally I need a solution which can accept a json object and return a json object fairly efficiently (it's going to run on mobile devices)

Comment: how are you ultimately displaying the content from the JSON response?

Comment: vanilla JavaScript concats the values with html and inserts into DOM innerHTML

Comment: you need to either run it through your own server on the way to amazon (pre-filtering), or be very very careful about displaying it on the client. with innerHTML, you're protected against <script> tags, but not the old "onmouseover" and it's relatives. you can use form inputs, textContent instead of innerHTML, or look into a client-side sanitizer: either code or free webservice.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was library which I could pass in the JSON object and it would do the sanitising for, can't seem to find one!

Comment: JSON doesn't need sanitizing, it encodes everything safely, only the decoded inner values could pose a risk.

Comment: yup, those values are what i'll be using, but i'm not going to loop through every attribute and value and sanitise it manually?